# how to fill value based on a Target condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in which a column has few unique values. I need to find the value for each unique value and create a new column names percentage such that the value filled out will be based on the target variable. Target(class) takes value from 0 to 9

for Example:

```
[![Gene
Class
0
FAM58A
1
1
CBL
2
2
CBL
2
3
CBL
3
4
CBL
4][1]][1]
```

to fill the value for above example

```
for ['FAM58A'] --> Target variable is 1 and it has only one value, so its value will be 1
for ['CBL'] --> we have 3 classes, namely two 2's, one 3, and one 4
so, value for 2 will be 2/4 = 0.5
value for 3 will be 1/4 = 0.25
value for 4 will be 1/4 = 0.25
```

I have the below code, but i am unable to add all values. it just adds the final value in the list

```
genes = ['SHOC2', 'TERT','CBL']
    t4 = np.zeros([262,3])
    for gene in genes:
        t1 = gene
        t2 = df[df['Gene'] == gene].groupby(['Class'])['Class'].count() / len(df[df['Gene'] == gene])
        t3 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':t1,'Class':t2.index,'Percentage':t2.values})
```

what i need to modify here so that i get the value for each genes and not only for 'CBL'